# Error: this.element.uniqueId is not a function. JQuery UI. Anyone seen this before?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Content/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Content/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Content/Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Content/Scripts/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Content/Scripts/jquery.ui.menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Content/Scripts/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Content/Scripts/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
```

So that's the sum of my script and stylesheet imports, but when it attempts to "convert" one of the `<select>` elements to the JQuery UI Selectmenu, I get this error in Mozilla Web Developer in the jquery.ui.selectmenu.js, and the jquery esque theme is not applied.

I've seen similar errors before caused by the scripts being important in the wrong order and the method not existing, but can't seem to think what may be causing it here.

Any ideas would be fantastic, more code can be given if needed, but its just a `<select>` element with `$('#exampleSelect').selectmenu();` applied to it.

Comment: hi @Christian, i have same problem, any solution?

Comment: It is funny, i used Firefox to copy the source code of an example in this url, http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/demos/selectmenu/default.html, i even copied the .js, saved all in my computer, now, i don't get this error anymore, but, still not working as it should

Comment: No solution as yet :(. I'll try a similar thing.

Comment: Please, let me know if you get any workarround to this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Just a random shot in the dark. According to [jQuery UI 1.9 upgrade guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#added-uniqueid-and-removeuniqueid-methods), the method `.uniqueId()` was only introduced in jQuery UI 1.9. Your version probably doesn't support said method, or you might be mixing different versions.

Answer (score 4):

Change line 33 in *jquery.ui.selectmenu.js* from:

```js
var selectmenuId = this.element.uniqueId().attr( "id" );
```

to:

```js
var selectmenuId = this.element.attr( 'id' ) || 'ui-selectmenu-' + Math.random().toString( 16 ).slice( 2, 10 );
```

This will hopefully work.