# this.element.uniqueId is not a function. JQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have using jquery ui and jquery ui selectmenu.

Here is versions of dependencies in package.json

> "jquery": "^3.3.1",
>    +    "jquery-ui": "^1.11.2",
>    +    "jquery-ui.selectmenu.extended": "^1.1.0",

But when I'm run project, I get this

TypeError: this.element.uniqueId is not a function

I changed those rows

```
var selectmenuId = this.element.uniqueId().attr( "id" );
var selectmenuClass = this.element.uniqueId().attr( "class" );
```

To those

```
var selectmenuId = this.element.attr( 'id' ) || 'ui-selectmenu-' + Math.random().toString( 16 ).slice( 2, 10 );
    var selectmenuClass = this.element.attr( 'class' ) || 'ui-selectmenu-' + Math.random().toString( 16 ).slice( 2, 10 );
```

And now I have this error

> : this.element.zIndex is not a function

How I can solve it, and is it right way to solve 1 problem, like I did?

**UPDATE**

Okay, I solve first problem, but now I have problem with z-index

Here

```
this.listWrap
        .removeAttr( 'style' )
        .zIndex( this.element.zIndex() + 2 )
        .position( $.extend( positionDefault, o.positionOptions ) );
}
```

> this.element.zIndex is not a function

Comment: have you tried it like this `$(this).uniqueId()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266653/how-do-i-use-uniqueid-jquery-ui
This answer can help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: this.element.uniqueId is not a function. JQuery UI. Anyone seen this before?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229617/error-this-element-uniqueid-is-not-a-function-jquery-ui-anyone-seen-this-befo)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use uniqueId() jquery ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266653/how-do-i-use-uniqueid-jquery-ui)

Comment: I need to change code inside of jquery.ui.selectmenu? @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: This error inside of plugin js @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: I updated post@RandyCasburn

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you had was that `this.element.uniqueId` was not a `function`, which means that either `this.element` was `undefined`, or `this.element.uniqueId` is something else instead of a `function`.

In your second code

```
this.listWrap
        .removeAttr( 'style' )
        .zIndex( this.element.zIndex() + 2 )
        .position( $.extend( positionDefault, o.positionOptions ) );
}
```

`zIndex` was something you had problem with, which is not surprising in view that it is a CSS property. You could do it like this:

```
    yourobject.css('z-index', parseInt(this.element.css('z-index')) + 2 )
```